# Mui React Tabs not Showing Data from Array.map

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tabs

I can show static data just fine using the React MUI Tabs component but I can't figure out why I can't map data. My code below shows fine for the second tab, and nothing for the first.

I even installed a different library (react-tabs) and had the exact same issue, so I think it's something that I'm missing fundamentally about how Tabs work.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


const Component = () => {

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  function TabPanel(props) {
    const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;
  
    return (
      <div
        role="tabpanel"
        hidden={value !== index}
        id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
        aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
        {...other}
      >
        {value === index && (
          <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
            {children}
          </Box>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  TabPanel.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
    index: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  };
  
  function a11yProps(index) {
    return {
      id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
      'aria-controls': `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,
    };
  }

  const chemicals = [
    {
        "Qty_per_100L": "",
        "ChemicalName": "Hert",
        "Water_Rate": "222",
        "Unit": "Kilograms",
        "Qty_per_Ha": "22"
    },
    {
        "Unit": "Grams",
        "Qty_per_100L": "22",
        "ChemicalName": "Fret",
        "Water_Rate": "1333",
        "Qty_per_Ha": ""
    },
    {
        "Qty_per_Ha": "42",
        "Unit": "Litres",
        "Water_Rate": "1131",
        "Qty_per_100L": "",
        "ChemicalName": "Blapper"
    },
    {
        "Qty_per_100L": "",
        "ChemicalName": "Hullpy",
        "Water_Rate": "123",
        "Unit": "Litres",
        "Qty_per_Ha": "2"
    }
]
    

  return (

      <Container component="main" maxWidth="xl">



      <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}>
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="basic tabs example">
          <Tab label="Tab 1" {...a11yProps(0)} /> 
          <Tab label="Tab 2" {...a11yProps(1)} />
        </Tabs>
      </Box>


      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
      <Box
          sx={{
            marginTop: 8,
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}
        >
    <List>
        {chemicals.map((chemical) => {
          <ListItem>
<ListItemText>{chemical.ChemicalName}</ListItemText>
</ListItem>
        })}
        </List>
        </Box>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
What
      </TabPanel>
      </Container>
  );
}
export default Component;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this code only

```
<List>
     {chemicals.map((chemical) => (
     <ListItem>
       <ListItemText>{chemical.ChemicalName}</ListItemText>
     </ListItem>
     ))}
</List>
```

or

````
<List>
        {chemicals.map((chemical) => {
          return(<ListItem>
<ListItemText>{chemical.ChemicalName}</ListItemText>
</ListItem>)
        })}
        </List>
    ```
````

Comment: Thanks very much, I feel stupid that I couldn't figure it out.